# paypal express checkout stopped working

Tags: magento2, paypal-express

Paypal express checkout stopped working.
I found in firebug net panel
400 bad request for url `rest/default/V1/carts/mine/selected-payment-method`
with response json `{"message":"The requested Payment Method is not available."}`
Even payment method is enabled and showing in checkout page.

I have no debug log for this.
Paypal express is working fine in staging with sandbox account.

Anyone have any clue why this happening and how can i debug this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to edit the apache conf file (in /etc/apache2/sites-available) as follow:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/rootfolder"  
    <Directory "/path/to/your/rootfolder">  
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        # AllowOverride All      # Deprecated  
        # Order Allow,Deny       # Deprecated  
        # Allow from all         # Deprecated  
        # --New way of doing it  
        Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

hope it will help you